# Segmentation fault causes previous function to not occur

Tags: c

Working on a project where I'm creating a linked list from items in a 2d array.  The array has been populated correctly, but my method for creating the linked list is causing a segmentation fault.  While trying to debug where the fault was occurring, I put a print statement one line above the method call, but the print statement never printed.  But, if i commented out the method call, the print statement did print.

```
main()
{
        struct String *list;
        char words1[100][1000];
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                words1[i][0] = '\0';

        char *words2[100];

        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                words2[i] = words1[i];

        char ** words = words2;

        getStrings(words);

        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
                if(words[i][0] == '\0') break;
                printf("%s\n", words[i]);
        }

        printf("Creating list\n"); //**(RIGHT HERE)** <-----------
        //createList(list, words);
        //sortStrings(list);
        showStrings(list);
        return 0;
}

struct String
{
        char *s;
        struct String *next;
};

void createList(struct String * list, char **words)
{
        list = NULL;
        struct String *node;

        int counter = 0;
        while (1)
        {
                if (words[counter][0] == '\0') break;

                printf("Adding: %s", words[counter]);

                node = (struct String *) malloc(sizeof(struct String));
                node->s = words[counter];
                node->next = NULL;
                list->next = node;
                list = node;
                counter++;
        }
}

void getStrings(char **s)
{
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        int ret = scanf("%[^;]", s[i]);
        if(ret < 0) break;
        count++;
        getchar();
    }
}
```

Why would a segmentation fault in the createList() method cause a function that should have been called before it to not execute (or at least not show up)?

Edit: Added getStrings() method to code.

Comment: Because you are most likely trashing the stack or other memory.  You should not expect your program to behave properly after a segfault.

Comment: 1) `list->next = node;` : `list` is `NULL` at first time. 2) `list` is uninitialized in `main`. (`createList` doesn't update `list` in `main`)

Comment: String is an exceedingly poor choice for a list node struct.

Comment: Best to also post `getStrings()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`printf` function does not write data to standard output immediately, as it might be too slow to do. Instead it might collect data in an internal buffer of `stdout` object. Once buffer gets full (or sometimes when newline is reached) its content gets "flushed" (written to the underlying file). During normal execution this data is also written before program exits, but because your program gets terminated beforehand, it is not able to empty that buffer, losing data.

You can add `fflush(stdout);` statement after `printf` to force data to be written.

Normally when writing to terminal buffer is flushed at `\n`. I suspect you are writing to a pipe instead (might be your IDE redirects your program output).

You can read more abut file streams here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c

And about `fflush` here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fflush

You can also use `setvbuf` function to manipulate file object buffering: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/setvbuf

Answer (score 0):

```
    main()
    {
    /* uninitialized list head must be initialized as NULL */
    struct String *list = NULL; 
    . . .       

    void createList(struct String * list, char **words)
    {
    /* Value of list changing only in local scope, list must be a      
       `struct String **` type.   */
    list = NULL;
    . . .
            /* access to field on NULL pointer -> segmentation fault */  
            list->next = node;
```